# Multicast delegates - multiple classes receiving notifications from UI controls in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I understand that UI controls such as UITextField notify of client interactions / events via their delegate, which is defined as a class that supports the required protocol.

I have often found myself wanting to receive notifications of UI event in more than one class, so would want to support multicasting. For example, specifying more than one delegate for a UI control. I am pretty sure that there is no iOS framework feature that supports this. I was wondering if anyone had come up with a decent solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a cocoa feature that lets you build multicast delegates with relative ease - it's the [*Message Forwarding*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) system built into the framework.

Make a class that overrides `forwardInvocation:`, and return an instance of your object instead of a delegate. This is what is sometimes called a *"Trampoline object"*. The logic inside your `forwardInvocation:` implementation can now decide which "real" objects should receive the message, and forward the invocation to one or more of them.

As an update to this accepted answer, I created my own multicasting delegate implementation here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/11/a-multicast-delegate-pattern-for-ios-controls/

Comment: Thanks for highlighting a very interesting language feature that I was not aware of. I think I can build what I require using this.

Comment: In Collin's example, missing thing is You need to add this: signature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes: "@^v^c"]; to (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector method.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your UI control in your class, and then your class will receive notification from this UI, you can send message to another class (using the same delegate technic - implement delegate property in first class, and then in second class implement delegate method from 1-st class).
For example, for UITextField method -textFieldDidEndEditing:

In first class -

1) implement protocol:

```
@protocol TextControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional // Delegate protocols
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;

@end
```

2) `@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained, readwrite) id <TextControllerDelegate> delegate;`

3)in method - `(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` inside the class, call `[delegate textFieldDidEndEditing:textField]`

In second class:

1) implement object of first class, set delegate to self (to second class).

2) implement method - `(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

Answer (score 1):

One technique to support multicasting is to give your delegating class the following methods:

`@interface Delegator : NSObject
- (void)addDelegate:(id<MyProtocol>)delegate;
- (void)removeDelegate:(id<MyProtocol>)delegate;
@end`

And store the reference to the delegates in an `NSHashTable`.

See the implementation here:
http://arielelkin.github.io/articles/objective-c-multicast-delegate/